# Will upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 cause loss of UI settings / choices?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, gui, mate

Due to a software program I use, I am compelled to upgrade to (at least) the 20.04 release.  I believe I have a Gnome / Mate desktop.  I suspect when the upgrade finishes, my "look & feel" will drastically change.  I'm really not keen on doing the tedious rebuild of the desktop.  Is there some upgrade choice I can make to keep my current environment as-is, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you cannot keep your old look and feel.

The desktop environment is rebuilt anew for different releases of Ubuntu.
Migrating to a different release means migrating to a different build.